# Using nested for-if-else on a data frame in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to use an if-else loop nested in a for loop to go through a data frame and output a new data frame based on conditions from the first df.

In this data frame I would like to compare each row N with row N+1,

if column elements match in column 1 and 2

and the difference between column values in columns 3 and 4 for row N and row N+1 are less than or equal to 1

then I would like to write a new row in the N+1 row spot

that has the same elements for col 1 and 2 as those in row N+1

and the minimum value of column 3 when comparing N and N+1 for col 3

and the maximum value of column 4 for comparing N and N+1 for col 4

Example:

```
aaa <- c(rep("cat",4), "dog", "dog")
bbb <- c("fit", rep("fat",2), rep("fat", 3))
ccc <- c(6,5,6,9,9,9)
ddd <- c(11,10,10,22,23,24)
df <- data.frame(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd)
```

Go from this:

```
 aaa bbb ccc ddd
 cat fit   6  11
 cat fat   5  10
 cat fat   6  10
 cat fat   9  22
 dog fat   9  23
 dog fat   9  24
```

To the desired output:

```
 aaa bbb ccc ddd
 cat fit   6  11
 cat fat   5  10
 cat fat   9  22
 dog fat   9  24
```

My attempt is this:

```
result <- data.frame()
for (i in c(1:as.numeric(nrow(df))-1)){      
  if(df[i,1] == df[i+1,1]
     &
     df[i,2] == df[i+1,2]
     &
     abs(df[i,3]-df[i+1,3]) <=1
     &
     abs(df[i,4]-df[i+1,4]) <=1)       
   {
    result[i+1,] <- c(df[i,1],df[i,2],min(df[i,3],df[i+1,3]),max(df[i,4],df[i+1,4]))
    result[i,] <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
    } else {
    result[i,] <- df[i,]
    }
}
result
```

Comment: In your example output, in column `ccc` you have both the `min` and `max` for `cat fat`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, when col 1 and 2 are equal in row N and N+1, take the min of col 3 and the max of col 4 between row N and N+1. Sorry if this wasnt clear

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not clear. Column `ccc` is column 3 and you have both the `min` and the `max`. If you now say again that you just want the `min`, and the max of column 4, `ddd`, then your posted example output is wrong?

Comment: All of the conditions must be true to make a comparison between the rows, ie for i=1, col[1,1]==col[2,1], col[1,2] != col[2,2], therefore write a row that is the same as row 1. I am not trying to take the minimum of the entire row, just the minimum between the 2 rows when all the conditions are met.

Comment: Will this do it for column 3? `tapply(df$ccc, paste(df$aaa, df$bbb), FUN = min)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Posting for closure:

```
result <- df
for (i in c(1:as.numeric(nrow(df)-1))){
  if(df[i,1] == df[i+1,1] &
     df[i,2] == df[i+1,2] &
     abs(df[i,3]-df[i+1,3])<=1 &
     abs(df[i,4]-df[i+1,4])<=1) {
    result[i+1,3] <- min(df[i,3],df[i+1,3])
    result[i+1,4] <- max(df[i,4],df[i+1,4])
    result[i,] <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
    } 
}
result <- na.omit(result)
result
```